# Resolve Python Indent Errors

Tags: python, notepad++, indentation

Python: version 3.6

Editor: Notepad++

Link to files: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/python_indent)

---

I added two lines to `process_string.py` and get errors

`File "process_string.py", line 14
    if i.find(k)!=-1 and flag==False:
                                    ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

In Notepad++ I went to **View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters** which shows two rows of three red arrows.

If I try to delete the red arrows I still get indent error.

How to fix?

[image]

Comment: It's complaining you are mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Replace the tabs with spaces. If the red arrows indicate tabs, delete the red arrows and replace each red arrow with four spaces. Three red arrows would be replaced with 12 spaces.

Comment: Thank you both, now it works

Comment: best thing is to download `pycharm` and press `CTRL+ALT+L` it will auto indent whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use tabs or spaces. Delete the indents and use any one .

Comment: This works now, thank you